# How to multiply a number of a list by the number of previous zeros on list?

Tags: python, list, math, count, iteration

I am have the following list:

```
[0.0,
 3.4,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 3.3,
 3.3,
 4.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 3.3,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 3.5,
 3.8,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 3.25,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 4.75,
 3.3,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 3.4,
 4.75,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 3.25,
 0.0,
 3.2,
 0.0]
```

In this list, the 0 represents for instance when one loses a bet and when is a number > 0, means one has won a bet with odds of 3.4. I am however trying to create a cumulative list based on this list. Meaning, based on this the list, the cumulative list should be (assuming we are betting -5):

```
[-5, 3.4*10,-5,-10,-20,-40,-80,-160,-320,3.3*640,3.3*5,4*5,-5,-10,-20,3.3*40]
```

Basically, one is doubling every time one looses the bet and resetting every time one wins the bet.

Comment: Please update the question with the code you have tried.

Comment: I would like to know if possible, in this list, when is a positive number higher than 0, how to multiply the number by previous number of 0's between the number higher than 0 and the previous one?

Comment: Are you asking how to do a factorial

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function with the following logic - for each value in the original list, check if it is greater than 0. If so, append to the return list the value of the current bet multiplied by that value, and return the current bet to the start bet. Otherwise, append `-1*curr_bet` to the return list and double the current bet.

```
def get_list(bets, start_bet):
    rv = []
    curr_bet = start_bet
    for bet in bets:
        if bet > 0:
            rv.append(curr_bet*bet)
            curr_bet = start_bet
        else:
            rv.append(-1*curr_bet)
            curr_bet = curr_bet*2
    return rv
```

Assuming `bets` is the list in your question, we can call the function like so:

```
>>> get_list(bets, 5)
[-5,
 34.0,
 -5,
 -10,
 -20,
 -40,
 -80,
 -160,
 -320,
 2112.0,
 16.5,
 20.0,
 -5,
 -10,
 -20,
 132.0,
 -5,
 -10,
 70.0,
 19.0,
 -5,
 -10,
 65.0,
 -5,
 -10,
 95.0,
 16.5,
 -5,
 -10,
 -20,
 -40,
 -80,
 -160,
 -320,
 -640,
 -1280,
 -2560,
 -5120,
 -10240,
 -20480,
 139264.0,
 23.75,
 -5,
 -10,
 -20,
 130.0,
 -5,
 32.0,
 -5]
```